# How can I change the DataGrid Foreground color based on user input?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a `DataGrid`. There are 12 columns in the `DataGrid`. Each of these columns represents `byte` values between 0-255. I want to colorize them depending on the ranges that the user enters.

I don't know how I can change these values based on user input. The user can specify different ranges for each column. Below is an application that I implemented manually. How can I bind this app to user login.

**Converter**

```
public class DataGridColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte data = (byte)value;

        if (data <= 30)
            return 0;
        else if (data <= 60)
            return 1;
        else if (data <= 90)
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:DataGridColorConverter x:Key="DGCConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding JobsCollectionView , IsAsync=True}"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Height="480">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RTR" Binding="{Binding RTR}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IDE" Binding="{Binding IDE}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DLC" Binding="{Binding DLC}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-0" Binding="{Binding Byte0}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-1" Binding="{Binding Byte1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-2" Binding="{Binding Byte2}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-3" Binding="{Binding Byte3}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-4" Binding="{Binding Byte4}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-5" Binding="{Binding Byte5}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-6" Binding="{Binding Byte6}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BYTE-7" Binding="{Binding Byte7}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Byte7,Converter={StaticResource DGCConverter}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Byte7,Converter={StaticResource DGCConverter}}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Byte7,Converter={StaticResource DGCConverter}}" Value="3">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TIME" Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note** : I am using MVVM.

**Note 2**: I did not share the fields where the user can enter value ranges so that it is not crowded in XAML.

For example, the user wanted `Blue` between 0-100, `Red` between 100-150, `Green` between 150-255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how I can change these values based on user input. The user can specify different ranges for each column.

If a user can specify the ranges, e.g. through `Slider`s or `TextBox`es, those values need to be bound in order to react to changes. Let's assume that the brushes that these values map to do not need to be bound (yet). An `IValueConverter` can only bind a single value. You could instead create an [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), which can bind multiple values as its name suggests. There are multiple options how a concrete converter could look like, depending on your view, view model and other requirements.

The following is an example of an [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) that allows binding multiple `byte` properties, where the first is the original `data` value to be compared and the rest represent the boundaries of each range. The `Brush`es for these ranges are passed as `parameter` (a collection) and are not bindable. If you would like them to be bindable, too, they would be passed though the `values` arrays as well. This converter assumes that all values are `byte`s and the `parameter` is a collection of `Brush`es. Furthermore, there must be *distinct* boundaries of ranges (no duplicates) and an equal number of `Brush`es (can be duplicates), otherwise there is no 1:1 mapping (throws an exception). If there are no bound values or no possible mapping, no brush will be returned.

```
public class DataGridColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values == null)
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      var byteValues = values.Cast<byte>().ToList();
      var brushes = ((IEnumerable)parameter).Cast<Brush>().ToList();

      var data = byteValues[0];
      var bounds = byteValues.Skip(1).Distinct().ToList();

      if (bounds.Count != brushes.Count)
         throw new ArgumentException("The number of distinct stops must be equal to the number of stop brushes.");

      foreach (var (boundary, brush) in bounds.Zip(brushes))
      {
         if (data <= boundary)
            return brush;
      }

      return Binding.DoNothing;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

In XAML, you can adapt your style with a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) using the new converter.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground">
      <Setter.Value>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridColorConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
               <!-- ...binds the current data context, your BYTE 7. -->
               <Binding/>
               <!-- ...these bindings may vary depending on the source for binding, view model, text block, ... -->
               <Binding Path="MyBlueRangeEndProperty"/>
               <Binding Path="MyRedRangeEndProperty"/>
               <Binding Path="MyGreenRangeEndProperty"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
               <!-- ...this array could also be shared (moved to resource and refernce via {StaticResource ...}). -->
               <x:Array Type="{x:Type Brush}">
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
               </x:Array>
            </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
         </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

As stated above, there are plenty of options to implement this. This should be sufficient for your use-case and enable you to even share the color array if it is the same for all columns or define each individually.

---

Update for the comment about compilation errors with [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0). This extension method is not available on all target frameworks. The same applies to the C# language version and tuple deconstruction. However, in these cases you can use a simple `for` loop instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bounds.Count; i++)
{
   if (data <= bounds[i])
      return brushes[i];
}
```

Comment: Great, I came to a conclusion close to this answer. But I still had question marks in my mind. Question marks are gone. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting a number of errors in the foreach inside the convert function. "No overload for method 'Zip' takes 1 argument" and "Connot inter the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable ('boundart') or ('brush')"  I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. I wrote a for loop that returns colors and values instead of foreach. As far as I understand, it's a case with the C# version. Should I edit the answer?

Comment: @saklanmaz Thanks. See my lastest edit, I added an explanation and an alternative for older frameworks and C# language versions.

Comment: In addition; If there is a very intense data flow, I think this process is slow. It gets confused in the UI if Binding.DoNothing returns. there is no problem for the background if Brushes.Transparent is used instead.